# Find all functions $f$ analytic in the open unit disk and such that $f(\frac{1}{n})= e^{-n} $

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

Find all functions $f$ analytic in the open unit disk and such that  $$f(\frac{1}{n})= e^{-n} $$
I don't know how to  start

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287448/if-f-is-analytic-and-f1-n-e-n-for-all-n-0-why-is-fz-0-fo and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701284/show-that-there-does-not-exist-any-analytic-function-for-which-f-left-dfrac1

Comment: And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185504/does-there-exist-an-analytic-function-s-t-f-left-frac1n-right-2-n

Comment: Can anyone tell, what kind of singularity  the function have?